# HTML5 Video Transition Effects

Tags: jquery, css, html, effects, transition

Is there a way to emulate video transition effects in HTML5 like this:

http://www.flash-filter.net/mask-transition-effect.phtml

Across all browsers? Safari, firefox, chrome, ie9?

Comment: I swear I saw this somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) has similar effects